How can I get the proposer graffiti of a specific ethereum block?
From what I've seen so far it should be extraData from the block header. However, that doesn't seem to be the case since every block I check the extraData returns something like 0x6265617665726275696c642e6f7267 (block 20933594).
Is this actually the graffiti and it's just encoded? If so, how would I go about decoding it?
If that's not the graffiti, what's the proper way to get it?

The graffiti is in the extraData field but it's in hexidecimal format and needs to be converted.
Using Python 3:
import binascii

def get_graffiti(block_data):
  hex_string = block_data['result']['extraData'].replace('0x','')
  graffiti = binascii.unhexlify(hex_string).decode('utf-8')
  return graffiti

